# Make up for lack of 300ms delay

Tags: google-chrome, mobile

I have a drawer menu on the mobile version of my website (built in Webflow). You click on a hamburger icon and the menu slides out from the right.

On Safari and other browsers that have the 300ms delay, the drawer slides out correctly, and then the link is clicked. However, on Chrome, which doesn't have the delay, the first menu link is clicked automatically as soon as the drawer slides out.

Hopefully you can see the issue in this gif: when I click the link normally on Chrome, Link 1 is automatically clicked. However, if I do a click and hold, it works normally.

[image: When I click the link normally on Chrome, Link 1 is automatically clicked. However, if I do a click and hold, it works normally.]

Is there a way to avoid this issue (without doing something kind of hacky like detecting if it's Chrome and adding a timeout back in)? Am I diagnosing the issue correctly?

Comment: Instead of links, I would leave the menu as just text so you don't have the unintended click problem. Right after the user opens the menu, you then add event handlers to the texts so that a click on these text items links to where your links are currently pointing. And when the user closes the menu, turn off the handlers. That way the links only fire after the menu is fully opened, regardless of the device.

Comment: Ah, this is a good solution. I'll give it a try, thanks!